# Dropping columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, slice

I'm on Python 2.7. I have a dataframe with 200 columns and need to drop a few.

I can use the below to drop the last n columns. How do I write it so i can drop the first 10, then column 22, then 26, 10th from the last, and last 5. All in one line.

```
df2 = df.iloc[:, :-5]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
import numpy as np
df.drop(df.columns[np.r_[:10, 22, 26, -10, -5:0]], axis=1)
```

---

np.r_ concatenates several slices. For example, `np.r_[1:3, 5, 7:9, -3:0]` returns `array([ 1,  2,  5,  7,  8, -3, -2, -1])`. You can use this to index into `df.columns`. For a DataFrame of 40 columns (named `A1:A40`),

```
df.columns[np.r_[:3, 5, 7:9, -2:0]]
Out: Index(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A6', 'A8', 'A9', 'A39', 'A40'], dtype='object')
```

And finally, since it takes index labels, you can pass this to `df.drop`. The resulting DataFrame will have the following columns:

```
df.drop(df.columns[np.r_[:3, 5, 7:9, -2:0]], axis=1).columns
Out: 
Index(['A4', 'A5', 'A7', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12', 'A13', 'A14', 'A15', 'A16',
       'A17', 'A18', 'A19', 'A20', 'A21', 'A22', 'A23', 'A24', 'A25', 'A26',
       'A27', 'A28', 'A29', 'A30', 'A31', 'A32', 'A33', 'A34', 'A35', 'A36',
       'A37', 'A38'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: thanks, how do i also add a range in between, say drop col 12-15?

Comment: You can change the np.r_ part to `np.r_[:10, 12:15, 22, 26, -10, -5:0]`. If you pass this to `df.drop` (as indexers to `df.columns`)) then it will drop columns 12-13-14 too.